# Ruby, iterate objects array in the right order

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have an array of objects and every object respond to the 'order' method.

I can write the method

```
objects = Objects.all
objects.each do |i|
 puts i.order
end
```

but I'm not sure the order is correct. Is there any fast way to iterate my array following the right order of every object?

**Update: real case.**

```
class Articles < ActiveRecord::Base
 as_many :article_pages
end

a = Article.find(2345)
pages = a.article_pages
pages.each ...
pages.first.order = 1
pages.last.order = 5
```

I need to iterate in my pages following order...

```
a.article_pages.order('order').each
```

doesn't work

Comment: my objects are saved in the db with an order.

So if I call object.order i obtain 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

I need that the iteration follow this order.

Comment: Is this a rails question ?

Comment: no, I'm using Sinatra with ActiveRecord

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, ActiveRecord will not guarantee any order.  To change that, use:

```
a = Article.find(2345)
pages = a.article_pages.order('order asc')
```

to order by a column.  Switch `asc` to `desc` to order in descending order.

Comment: Updated solution.  Next time paste the code you actually tried, rather than changing it up after the fact.

Comment: Are you sure about "By default, ActiveRecord will order by primary key in ascending order."? If there's no ORDER BY sent to the database then you'll often get them back in PK order but no particular order is guaranteed unless you give the database an explicit ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Edited.  Good catch, its the underlying DB that decides what the default sort order is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort option in case you want it in ascending only

```
a = Article.find(2345)
pages = a.article_pages.all.sort_by &:order
```